# Labview : Attaching caption or label on lines in waveform graph

Tags: labview

[image]

White, red, and green lines are some levels, according to a criterion, and blue line is measured spectrum, in upper picture.

Now, I want to attach the names of the lines, corresponding to levels, on the right end of lines.

The below picture is what I expect.

[image]

I couldn't find any plot property for these work.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **Annotation List** property to set annotations at specific points in the graph and I believe also link them to plots.

I have no practical experience with it, so I'm not familiar with all it can do. It might also give you the ability to manipulate specific annotations, etc. Play with it and see.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for the problem: https://lavag.org/topic/17756-xy-graph-programmatically-add-point-labels/

It uses **Annotation List** property as *Yair* told already.